# I need to loop through a complex JSON ARRAY of objects to return only two items using LODASH with Typescript

Tags: typescript, lodash

This is a complex JSON object...

Here's a bit of the code:

```
    entity: [{entityName: "Nrm", page: 0, pageSize: 241, status: "successfully perfrom: select Operation",…}]
    0: {entityName: "Nrm", page: 0, pageSize: 241, status: "successfully perfrom: select Operation",…}
    entityName: "Nrm"
    page: 0
    pageSize: 241
    rows: [{columns: [{paramName: "country_alpha3_code", paramValue: "PLW", dataType: "String"},…]},…]
    [0 … 99]
    0: {columns: [{paramName: "country_alpha3_code", paramValue: "PLW", dataType: "String"},…]}
    columns: [{paramName: "country_alpha3_code", paramValue: "PLW", dataType: "String"},…]
    0: {paramName: "country_alpha3_code", paramValue: "PLW", dataType: "String"}
    dataType: "String"
    paramName: "country_alpha3_code"
    paramValue: "PLW"
    1: {paramName: "country_name", paramValue: "PALAU", dataType: "String"}
    dataType: "String"
    paramName: "country_name"
    paramValue: "PALAU"
    2: {paramName: "country_alpha2_code", paramValue: "PW", dataType: "String"}
    dataType: "String"
    paramName: "country_alpha2_code"
    paramValue: "PW"
```

Here's how it looks with a script snip:

[image]

What I want is a simple JSON Object for a country Drop Down and no, they are not going to build a custom API to do this so I'm doing it in Typescript and Lodash

```
countries = {
  [{
      name: "United States",
      code: "US"
  },{
      name: "Canada",
      code: "CN"
  },{
      name: "Italy",
      code: "IT"
  },
  ....]

}
```

That's it.

Here's my typescript function where I want to make the new JSON Object

```
async getCountryOptions() {
  // this.services.getCountries();
  const response = await this.services.getCountries();

  // console.log('RESPONSE AFTER AWAIT: ', response);
  
  this.countries = this.services.countryList;

  console.log('Did we get countries: ', this.countries);

  // Now to make a new array for only country code and name
  ****************** HERE *********************


  // I TRIED THIS but I got ...val is not an iterator
  this.newJSONCountryArr = Object.entries(this.countries)
    .map(([key, val]) => [...val, key]);
  console.log('Result: ', this.newJSONCountryArr);

  if (this.countries) {
    this.meta.countryOptions.push(this.services.countryList);
  } else {
    console.log('Whoops! ')
  }
}
```

Comment: _"This is a complex JSON object"_ - No. That's an array of _objects_, because [there's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: What is going wrong? / what do you need help with?

Comment: Xiddic, what's wrong is I'm just trying to find a simple way to loop through the example and return only two items in a new ARRAY of OBJECTS for countries, like we do for states.  The problem is the array of objects as Andreas stated, which is correct, and I changed the title, is that I'm having difficultly determining what I need to do in LODASH to accomplish said task.

Answer (score 0):

See the solution in the UPDATE above

```
// Now to make a new array for only country code and name
// ************* THIS IS THE SOLUTION **************
var results =_.map(this.countries, function(res) { 1
  console.log('result: ', { country_name: res.columns[1].paramValue, country_alpha2_code: res.columns[2].paramValue });
  return { country_name: res.columns[1].paramValue, country_alpha2_code: res.columns[2].paramValue }; 
});
```